# Plotting a smoothed line against lots of "noisy looking" original data in R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, smoothing, loess

I'm trying to convey a general impression of some noisy performance figures, so I think I want to plot a loess-smoothed curve of my original data. I should explicitly point out that throwing away some of the data's precision is totally fine; I merely want to point out that the figures I have form a (mostly) repeating pattern.

The reason I want to show this is so that I can prove I've considered all the data as a whole, and that examining e.g. a single day in more detail is not as lazy as it sounds.

I have tried to run smooth.spline and loess against my data, but I think that fails because of the way I'm calling ggplot. I believe I have to do a strange incantation of ggplot and ggsave because this code is actually inside a function, and calls to ggplot inside a function appear to go wrong because of something like scoping behaviour (not looked at this too closely; I don't understand R's scoping).

Here's some example code that shows what I'm trying:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")


iops_october <- read.csv("iops_oct.csv", header=TRUE)
iops_october <- subset(iops_october, select=c("read_iops", "write_iops", "total_iops", "time"))
iops_october$time <- as.POSIXct(iops_october$time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


molten_iops  <- melt(iops_october, id.vars="time")

#plot = ggplot(data=molten_iops, aes(x=time, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_line() + lines(smooth.spline(iops$time, iops$wrie_iops))
plot = ggplot(data=molten_iops, aes(x=time, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_line()

ggsave("october.svg", plot=plot, width=64, height=24, limitsize=FALSE)
```

As this needs a bit of data, you can find a ~100kbyte file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7640872/r/iops_oct.csv)

I suppose my ultimate aim would be to average out all the figures based on the time (throwing away the date component), but I think I can do that by creating an additional as.time column, and then averaging using that "time" as the group.

Comment: Why not geom_smooth()?

Comment: Errr because I didn't honestly know it was there! I googled a lot, and everything I found led me down the path of fitting a model to the data. geom_smooth looks totally fine, thank you.